# C++ simple array creation with user given length

Tags: c++, arrays

How to create one array in a method with user given length? I would like to fill in a vector with user given length with random numbers.

```
 double* Random::quasiRandomUnif(float a, float b, int NN) 
 {
     int i, errcode;

          N_=NN; // here initialize the member N_

          float r[N_];

     VSLStreamStatePtr stream;
     int i, errcode;

     errcode = vslNewStream( &stream, BRNG,  SEED );
     errcode = vsRngUniform( METHOD, stream, N_, r, a, b );

     double* rd = new double[m_N];
     for(int i=0;i<m_N;i++)
         rd[i]=(double)r[i];

     errcode = vslDeleteStream( &stream );

     return rd;
  }
```

I thought of N_ a member for the class Random, to be initialized in this function's body, with some user given value -- not possible, since space allocated in array should be a constant. How to deal with?

Kind regards.

Comment: If m_N is not known at compile time then you should allocate r as you did for rd. Remember to delete them or use them with auto_ptr.

Comment: @PaoloBrandoli You can't store a dynamically allocated array in an auto_ptr - that would be undefined behaviour when the auto_ptr is destroyed, since it'll call `delete` instead of `delete []`.   std::vector is the way forward here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, you should use the `vector` class:

```
std::vector<double> rd;
for(int i=0;i<m_N;i++) rd.push_back(r[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `new` operator.

```
float r = new float[m_N];
```

Remember to delete it, when you are done with it.

```
delete[] r;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Boost.ScopedArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm).  Simpler semantics than `vector` without the memory management overhead of your own raw array.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with the `r` array? Why not allocate that with `new` as well? Then you can use any expression you like as the size.